# scope and mime type for list excel files & export them in csv format from google drive

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

The below code is working to list the files. I just want to export the files in csv format. This code gives a list of all files. I want only excel files and on click I want to download them in csv format.

```
 var CLIENT_ID = '***********************';
    var API_KEY = '*************************';

var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';

function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY);
   // window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
}

function checkAuth() {
    var options = {
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES,
        immediate: true
    };
    gapi.auth.authorize(options, handleAuthResult);
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');

    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        makeApiCall();
    } else {
        authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
        authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
    }
}

function handleAuthClick(event) {
    var options = {
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES,
        immediate: false
    };
    gapi.auth.authorize(options, handleAuthResult);
    return false;
}

function makeApiCall() {  
    gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', makeRequest);   
}

function makeRequest() {

    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({'maxResults': 5 });
    request.execute(function(resp) {          

        for (i=0; i<resp.items.length; i++) {
            //console.log(resp);
            var titulo = resp.items[i].title;
            var fechaUpd = resp.items[i].modifiedDate;
            var userUpd = resp.items[i].lastModifyingUserName;
            var userEmbed = resp.items[i].embedLink;
            var userAltLink = resp.items[i].alternateLink;
            var fileInfo = document.createElement('li');
            fileInfo.appendChild(document.createTextNode('TITLE: ' + titulo));                
            document.getElementById('content').appendChild(fileInfo);
        }
    });    
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#authorize-button').on('click', handleAuthClick);
  $.getScript('//apis.google.com/js/api.js', function() {
    gapi.load('auth:client', handleClientLoad);
  });
});
```

How can i do this.

Comment: From your question, it's not clear what your problem is. Perhaps show the code where you are doing the files.list

Comment: I has updated the code please check and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `google.picker.ViewId.DOCUMENTS` to `google.picker.ViewId.DOCS`

See https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#ViewId for details.

This will list all files. If you want to limit it to a specific mime type, you'll need to create your own view. Something like

```
var myExcelView = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
myExcelView.setMimeTypes("application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"); // or whatever mime types you've used
var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
     .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
     .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
     .addView(myExcelView)
     .etc etc
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Here, if an answer solves your problem, you click the tick mark to Accept that answer. That is more effective than posting a thank you.

Comment: yes the answer helped me but doesn't lead me to solution.

Comment: then post a comment or update your question to explain why the answer is incomplete so we can help you

Comment: can i update my new code to my question to show you for the help? It means can I edit my question

Comment: hi pinoyyid. I got the list and also able to export excel in csv. The problem is I can only export the first sheet of google spreadsheet. How can I export all the sheets available in spreadsheet. Help If you can Please

Comment: My function is :    function downloadGDriveFile (file) {
var request1 = gapi.client.drive.files.export({
  'fileId': '1VLFgD8CNvXTVdHKyBdZPUmgFmhWMzg7qWLbxzLUTtSo',
  'mimeType': 'text/csv'
})
request1.then(function(response) {
  //console.log(response);
}, function(err) {
  console.log('Error');
  console.log(err.result.error);
});
}